# How to run a `for <-`inside a `for <-`in a template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a component that builds a menu that may have nested sub-menus:

```
Product A
Product B ------ Product B1
Product C        Product B2
                 Product B3
```

In my component I have this (simplified with parts removed) code:

```
<%= for {link_subMenuLinkNumber, id} <- Enum.with_index(@link_subMenuLinkNumber) do %>
    <a class="comp link" href="<%= link_subMenuLinkNumber.link %>"><%= link_subMenuLinkNumber.text %></a>
                               <%= if link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu do %>
         <%= for {link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu, id} <- Enum.with_index(@link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu) do %>
               <a class="comp link secondLayer subMenu ite" href="<%= link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu.linkSubMenu %>"><%= link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu.textSubMenu %></a>
         <% end %>
                               <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in the template where I insert this component I have this (simplified with parts removed) code:

```
link_subMenuLinkNumber: [
                          %{link: "/prod1", text: "LOLOL1", subMenu: nil},
                          %{link: "/prod2", text: "LOLOL2", subMenu: [
                                       %{textSubMenu: "KAKAka", linkSubMenu: "/subProdKA"},
                                       %{textSubMenu: "ZaZaza", linkSubMenu: "/subProdZA"}
                                                                     ]},
                          %{link: "/prod3", text: "LOLOL3", subMenu: nil}
                         ]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
...cannot invoke remote function link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu/0 inside match
```

With only one loop/level this is working but I've tried a few different approaches and I'm not able to make this work using this approach.
Can I make this work?

Comment: I think the problem is you're calling the map.something function inside a match. When you're pattern matching you must provide constructs that can actually match calling the function and trying to match it will break because you can't match a function (that can result in any value) to let's say a variable

Comment: Thank you Sasha. You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see this commonly when you use the `.` function (e.g. `link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu`

You can see this more easily with:

```
iex> %{foo: "foo"}.foo = "foo"
** (CompileError) iex:2: cannot invoke remote function %{foo: "foo"}.foo/0 inside match
```

In your case, you have:

```
<%= for {link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu, id} <- Enum.with_index(@link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu) do %>
```

Don't forget that here you are assigning a value, you can't assign a value to `link_subMenuLinkNnuber.subMenu.` Instead, I think you want:

```
<%= for {sub_menu, id} <- Enum.with_index(link_subMenuLinkNumber.subMenu) do %>
```

To prevent your `if` check, you could also change your data structure to use an empty list (`[]`) instead of `nil` to represent the end of a submenu. Depending on your use case, you may want to use a recursive data structure such as a tree to represent your menu.

Comment: Thank you Gazler. Also for the empty list tip!

Comment: I think you have a typo (because I use non standard syntax :) ) and you mean: `subMenu` instead of `sub_menu` in the `for {}`

Comment: @PauloJaneiro I definitely mean `sub_menu` - it is a variable. It can be called anything.